# The menu created using binding is different from the menu created using MaterialDesignThemes package

Tags: binding, menu, material-design

First of all, please understand that I am asking questions using a translator.

I am making an application with wpf.
The menu created using binding is different from the menu created using MaterialDesignThemes package.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKqwo.png).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXOH7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kiOt.png)

I need to mix both bindings and MaterialDesignThemes.
The menu creation should proceed through binding, and the shape should be the same as the result created in MaterialDesignThemes.

Attach cs and xaml sources.

```
xaml

<Window x:Class="EvoLogger.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Logger" 
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStyle="None"      
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        BorderThickness="1"
        ResizeMode ="CanResizeWithGrip"
        MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="800">

    <Grid Margin="0,5,0,5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Menu Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
            <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
                </Style>
            </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Menu.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MenuItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </Menu.ItemTemplate>
        </Menu>
        
        <Menu x:Name="mainMenu" IsMainMenu="True" Grid.Row="2">
            <Menu.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Menu.ItemsPanel>
            <MenuItem Header="_File" Height="40">
                <MenuItem
                            Header="Save"
                            Icon="{materialDesign:PackIcon Kind=ContentSave}">
                </MenuItem>

                <MenuItem Header="Save As.."/>

                <MenuItem
                            Header="Exit"
                            InputGestureText="Ctrl+E"
                            Icon="{materialDesign:PackIcon Kind=ExitToApp}"/>

                <Separator/>

                <MenuItem
                            Header="Excellent"
                            IsCheckable="True"
                            IsChecked="True"/>

                <MenuItem
                            Header="Rubbish"
                            IsCheckable="True"/>

                <MenuItem
                            Header="Dig Deeper"
                            InputGestureText="Ctrl+D">
                    <MenuItem
                                Header="Enlightenment?"
                                IsCheckable="True"/>
                    <MenuItem
                                Header="Disappointment"
                                IsCheckable="True"/>
                </MenuItem>

                <MenuItem
                            Header="Look Deeper"
                            InputGestureText="Ctrl+D">
                    <MenuItem Header="Plain"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Ice Cream"/>
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>

            <MenuItem Header="_Edit" Height="40">
                <MenuItem
                            Header="_Cut"
                            Command="Cut"
                            Icon="{materialDesign:PackIcon Kind=ContentCut}"/>

                <MenuItem
                            Header="_Copy"
                            Command="Copy"
                            Icon="{materialDesign:PackIcon Kind=ContentCopy}"/>

                <MenuItem
                            Header="_Paste"
                            Command="Paste"
                            Icon="{materialDesign:PackIcon Kind=Cog}"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Window>


cs
using System;
using System.Windows;
using EvoConfiguration;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Logger
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> MenuItems { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>
            {
                new MenuItemViewModel { Header = "Alpha" },
                new MenuItemViewModel { Header = "Beta",
                    MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>
                        {
                            new MenuItemViewModel { Header = "Beta1" },
                            new MenuItemViewModel { Header = "Beta2",
                                MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>
                                {
                                    new MenuItemViewModel { Header = "Beta1a" },
                                    new MenuItemViewModel { Header = "Beta1b" },
                                    new MenuItemViewModel { Header = "Beta1c" }
                                }
                            },
                            new MenuItemViewModel { Header = "Beta3" }
                        }
                },
                new MenuItemViewModel { Header = "Gamma" }
            };

            DataContext = this;
        }

        

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window2 w2 = new Window2();

            w2.Show();
        }

        private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            DragMove();
        }
    }

    public class MenuItemViewModel
    {
        private readonly ICommand _command;

        public MenuItemViewModel()
        {
            _command = new CommandViewModel(Execute);
        }

        public string Header { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> MenuItems { get; set; }

        public ICommand Command
        {
            get
            {
                return _command;
            }
        }

        private void Execute()
        {
            // (NOTE: In a view model, you normally should not use MessageBox.Show()).
            MessageBox.Show("Clicked at " + Header);
        }
    }

    public class CommandViewModel : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action _action;

        public CommandViewModel(Action action)
        {
            _action = action;
        }

        public void Execute(object o)
        {
            _action();
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object o)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { }
            remove { }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

Menu.ItemContainerStyle -> Style -> BaseOn / Add

```
<Menu Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
            <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
                </Style>
            </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Menu.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MenuItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </Menu.ItemTemplate>
        </Menu>

<Menu Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
            <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" **BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignMenuItem}"**>
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
                </Style>
            </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Menu.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MenuItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </Menu.ItemTemplate>
        </Menu>
```